# Finding the limit of decreasing function

Tags: limits, trigonometry

Given
$$x_1=\arctan2>x_2>x_3\dots\\
\sin(x_n-x_{n-1})=\frac1{2^{n+1}}\sin x_n \sin{x_{n-1}} $$

Find $\cot x_n$ and prove $\lim_{x\to\infty}x_n=\frac\pi4$

I found that $\cot x_n=\cot x_{n-1}-(1/{2^{n+1}})$

Im not sure how to proceed with the limit. If I put $x_n=x_{n-1}$ in above eq 
it evaluate to $0=0$

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2755844/find-cot-space-x-n-if-sinx-n1-x-n2-n1sin-space-x-nsin-space-x-n/2755864#2755864) could be helpful for you.

Comment: Wow. Like how. I used both google seach and stack exchange search. Teach me senpai

Comment: Never mind. 'cause that is what I happened to have answered yesterday :-)